# What is the best way in MySQL to get how many hours old something is?

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to run a query that uses how many hours old something is to give it a weight, so I'm hoping someone know a quick way to get how many hours old something is from the current date/time given a datetime field to compare off of.

E.g.: this link is 5 hours old, this link is 27 hours old

gracias :)

Comment: Why not do the sorting on the full precision, then convert to "hours ago" in your display layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you want the rounding, but perhaps you can just use [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

```
 select TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'2010-12-31 12:30:43','2010-12-31 14:11:12') as hours_old;
+-----------+
| hours_old |
+-----------+
|         1 |
+-----------+

 select TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'2010-12-30 12:30:43','2010-12-31 14:11:12') as hours_old;
+-----------+
| hours_old |
+-----------+
|        25 |
+-----------+
```

If you want to show this to a user, you might be better off converting the difference to seconds ( `select TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND ... )` and conditionally format it in code for display so it'll show "1 minute ago" "2 hours ago" ,"6 days ago" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(you_date_time)) / 3600
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into date arithmetic.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html